# BuddyPress | How to merge the "setting" & "profile" pages into one page?

Tags: buddypress, options, profiles

In BuddyPress I would like to merge the *register.php* and *setting.php* files into one "*register.php*".
Is that possible?

I don't want to change my Name, City and Address then go to the *setting page* to change email and password again.
Thanks for your answers :)